# How to validate an element is gone using webdriverIO, Mocha and Chai

Tags: mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

I'm working on some automated tests, using webdriverIO, Mocha and Chai. I keep running into the same problem when I want to verify if an element is deleted.

I'm working with a shoppingbasket where i delete an item and then verify that it is gone. It takes a while for the item to be gone though, so if I immediately go to the expect, the item is still there.

I have solved this by doing this:

```
browser.waitForExist(deletedProduct, 5000, true)
expect (boodschappenLijstPage.isProductPresent(SKU), 'the removed item was still there' ).to.equal(false)
```

The webdriverIO waitfor command waits for the product to dissapear, and after that the chai expect checks if it is gone.

The problem I have with this is that the expect will never fail. If the product is not properly deleted the waitfortimeout will throw an error before I get to the expect part, meaning that the expect part is only reached if the product is gone

I have read through the docs for chai, but I can't seem to find a way of doing this.

Can anyone show be a way of waiting for the product to be gone, without missing the expect (I don't want to use browser.pause for obvious reasons)

Comment: You want to wait and in the end of the wait to not timeout and return `false` (element is still displayed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to validate that an element is gone, then using `expect` is the correct solution, but you should use the Webdriver-expect assertions instead of the chai expect assertions. While chai assertions check the state *immediately*, the WebdriverIO-expect assertions have the waitFor functionality built inside of it.  Here is an example:

```
let deletedProduct = $(/* your xpath/CSS selector/*);
expect(deletedProduct).not.toBeDisplayed();
```

The difference between the assertion and using waitForDisplayed with the reverse flag is that some reporters, such as Allure, will report your test as *broken* when instead the test should be reported as *failed*.  For example, when we ran tests and had the waitForDisplayed, all of our failing tests were marked in *yellow*.  When we use expect, the tests are marked in *red*.

Here is the documentation for the [WebdriverIO Expect matchers](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/expect-webdriverio/#element-matchers).  They didn't document the `.not` method very clearly, but in my example you can see I added the .not before the toBeDisplayed call.

Again, this expect will wait for the timeout specified in the wdio.conf.js, just like the waitFors will.

Answer (score 4):

Refer [this](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForDisplayed.html)

```
webElement.waitForDisplayed({ reverse: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try catch` and basically wait for error. When element disappears from DOM selenium will throw `NoSuchElementError` and we can use it.

```
isNotPresent(element) {
  try {
    return !element.isVisible()
  } catch (error) {
    return true
  }
}

// or wait for element to disappear from dom

waitForNotVisible(element) {
  browser.waitUntil(() => {
    try {
      return !element.isVisible()
    } catch (error) {
      return true
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi @nEkis I was just wondering if you still follow through with this solution - or there has been another more efficient way since you've posted this?

Comment: Hi, I am still using this solution.

Comment: @AzySır - Please see my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66370170/552792